# What is WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner and WDA(WebDriverAgent)?

Tags: ios, webdriver, appium, appium-inspector

I want to do auto test at simulator.

In this process, I have some questions.

1. I fully know about WebDriverAgent is needed in this process.
   But, I don't know about WebDriverAgentRunner-Runner.
   what is that?
2. If I do test in simulator, I do nothing about WDA right?
   (Actually I have done nothing about WDA.)
   Appium server automatically install WDA server right?

But, According to internet, they install WDA through Xcode...
and set desired capabilities usePrebuiltWDA: true..

I use Desired Capabilities,

usePrebuiltWDA : false

I have a big stress about it..
If you know about this, please tell me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Appium will automatically install the WebDriverAgent app on the simulator device. Go ahead and create your Appium driver session without worrying about configuring the WebDriverAgent.